# If else condition not working on button click in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, button, android-activity

If I don't use any condition on click to call another Activity then it works, but when I use some condition then its not responding, neither calling `if` section nor `else`:

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server                     
            try {
                strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", null);
                strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", null);

                if (strGetEmail.equals("")&&strGetName.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Please create your account first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this, BasicActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    new UploadFileToServer().execute();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: `its not responding, neither calling if section nor else` means `catch` block is executed use `e.printStackTrace()` to check Exception

Comment: you gave default value null but checking it with "". this is a wrong checking

Comment: check it in catch block, there will be nullponterexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be space between && and strGetName.equals("") in if condition.

```
 if (strGetEmail.equals("") && strGetName.equals(""))
```

and change

```
strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", null);
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", null);
```

to

```
strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", "");
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException as your strings are most probably null. Check if you are writing values in the SharedPref **before** reading from  it.

Also, in the event that you don't want to write values in the local storage yet, you should be giving the default values of the strings as `pref.getString("key_name","")` or make sure that `strGetEmail!=null` before checking `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `if..else` section is not working because there is a   `NullpointerException` at the `if` statement. You may be calling `.equals` on a `null` value.

change this

```
strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", null);
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", null);
```

into this

```
strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", "");
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", "");
```

or change your `if` code like this,

```
 if (strGetEmail == null || strGetName== null) {
      ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just replace this piece of code

`strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", null);
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", null);`

with this piece of code

`strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", "");
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You always get the null value that you gave as default value . 
Change it according to this :

```
strGetName = pref.getString("key_name", "");
strGetEmail = pref.getString("key_email", "");
```